# How to run pidgin and login automatically on startup

Tags: startup, pidgin

How to run pidgin minimized to Panel and login automatically with the enabled accounts at startup. I am using pidgin 2.10.3 on ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is probably to add "pidgin" to the list of startup applications in ubuntu.

See the following:

[How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-to-start-applications-at-startup-automatically)

Comment: this procedure doesnot minimize pidgin to panel at the startup ! Also is there any way to hide it to panel ?